# Difference between Amazon cloud and its CDN(Content Distribution Networks)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, cdn

I'm reading *Computer Networking A Top-Down Approach*, in a section about CDN(Content Distribution Networks), it chooses Netflix as a case:

> As shown in Figure, this Web site (and its associated backend
> databases) run entirely on Amazon servers in the Amazon cloud.
> Additionally, the Amazon cloud handles the following critical
> functions:
>
> **Content ingestion.** Before Netflix can distribute a movie to its
> customers, it must first ingest and process the movie. Netflix
> receives studio master versions of movies and uploads them to hosts in
> the Amazon cloud.
>
> **Content processing.** The machines in the Amazon cloud
> create many different formats for each movie, suitable for a diverse
> array of client video players running on desktop computers,
> smartphones, and game consoles connected to televisions. A different
> version is created for each of these formats and at multiple bit
> rates, allowing for adaptive streaming over HTTP using DASH.
>
> **Uploading versions to its CDN.** Once all of the versions of a movie have been
> created, the hosts in the Amazon cloud upload the versions to its CDN.

[image]

I can't understand what's difference between Amazon cloud and its CDN.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Amazon CloudFront CDN is part of the 'AWS Cloud', but it distinct enough to considered somewhat separate.

From [Global Infrastructure Regions & AZs](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/), AWS has (as at Oct 2021):

- 25 Regions (plus 8 more announced)
- 218+ Edge Locations and 12 Regional Edge Caches

If you want to store data in Amazon S3, or create virtual computers in Amazon EC2, they operate in Data Centers in the **25 Regions** around the world.

Amazon CloudFront (which is their Content Distribution Network) **keeps caches in those 218+ locations**. There are more Edge Locations than Regions so that data can be kept 'closer' to users. In fact, there are sometimes multiple Edge Locations in the *same* city because they are located in facilities run by major network providers and ISPs, thereby reducing the latency when serving users on those major networks.

Amazon CloudFront is a 'pull' system. An Edge Location only caches content when it is requested by a user close to that Edge Location. It works like this:

- A user tries to access a website that is served by CloudFront
- DNS resolution of the domain name automatically redirects users to the 'closest' location (or, more accurately, the location with the lowest latency)
- If the requested data is already present in the cache, it is immediately returned.
- Otherwise, a request is sent to the *Origin*. Any data that is returned is then stored in the cache *and* returned to the user
- Any future request to that Edge Location will then be able to serve the cached content until it expires

So, your quotation is not quite accurate. It is not possible to 'upload' content to Amazon CloudFront. Instead, it is 'pulled' into the cache locations when requested.

Also, Netflix uses its own cache network by installing [Open Connect servers](https://openconnect.netflix.com/en_gb/) in the data centers of many large network providers and ISPs, thereby avoiding network costs and latency.